# @Render.Scripts in plain .html file - not in .cshtml

Tags: html, razor, scripting, bundle, render

I'm wondering - is it possible to add something like

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

in plain .html file (not the .cshtml file)

Comment: Your `.cshtml` is compiled to C# class by MVC (and `Scripts` is another class too). `.html` is just a text file. Things are not working this way. Try to move html markup to your `.cshtml` view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, you can use:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery3.js"></script>
```

Where jquery1.js, jquery2.js, jquery3.js are the files of the jquery bundle...