# How to use script bundles in plain html (not cshtml)?

Tags: html, scriptbundle

Before asking this question, I read the following two questions in Stack Overflow to avoid duplicate questions:

1) [@Render.Scripts in plain .html file - not in .cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362389/render-scripts-in-plain-html-file-not-in-cshtml)

2) [Rendering the script bundle in a plain HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513202/rendering-the-script-bundle-in-a-plain-html-page)

May I know how to use script bundles in plain html file *(something like `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")` in cshtml)*?

I want to bundle more than one script file *(to compress and load them together)* and use the bundle in plain html. This bundle is going to be used in more than one html file.

Please advise.

Comment: You'll have to bundle them yourself and include that script like in the first question you linked.

Comment: Should I include them as follows:

<script src="/Scripts/jquery1.js"></script>  
<script src="/Scripts/jquery2.js"></script>  
<script src="/Scripts/jquery3.js"></script>

If so, this is not bundling, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a script minifier/bundler, like [https://jscompress.com/](http://jscompress.com). Choose the "Upload Javascript Files" tab, and upload all the scripts you want there. It will produce a single, minified and bundled file, just like ASP.NET would. You can then include that single file in your code just like you wrote.